# Sub references as arguments

Tags: perl

Another Perl-beginner question, but strangely enough, I found no tutorial to explain me this simple problem.

I wanted, as an exercise, to write a function `map` that takes a function and an array, returning an array. In functional languages, this is used quite often and I heard about the sub references and how to use them.

```
sub map {
  my $f = shift;
  my @r = ();

  foreach (@_) {
    push(@r, &f($_));
  }
  return @r;
}

sub square {
  my $r = shift;
  return $r*$r;
}

print map(\&shift, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

But, for some reason, I only get the word `CODE` and a hex-number as an output, five times. I have then changed the call of `f` in `map`, to `$$f($_)` and `$f->($_)` but all of it had the same result.

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: perl have buildin `map` function, did you notice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. perl have a builin `map` function. let's call it `map2`
2. use `&$f` to dereference `$f`
3. use `join` to print an array properly

---

```
sub map2 {
  my $f = shift;
  my @r = ();

  foreach (@_) {
    push(@r, &$f($_));
  }
  return @r;
}

sub square {
  my $r = shift;
  return $r*$r;
}

print join ",", map2(\&square, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

---

```
$ perl 1.pl
1,4,9,16,25
```

Comment: `&$f($_)` is also writable as `$f->($_)` which, IMO, looks nicer. May just be me, though.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, Perl has a built in `map` function that you should use.

```
my @squares = map {$_ ** 2} 1 .. 5;
```

Rather than passing an argument, Perl's built in `map` sets `$_` to each element, which allows you to write your `square` function succinctly as either `{$_ * $_}` or `{$_ ** 2}`

But Perl also gives you the ability to make custom map-like functions with a similar syntax. For example, say you wanted to write a version of `map` that maps over pairs of values:

```
sub pair_map (&@) {     # the (&@) prototype here tells perl that the sub
    my $code = shift;   # takes a code block, and then a list, just like `map`
    my @ret;        
    while (@_) {
        push @ret, $code->(splice @_, 0, 2);
    }
    @ret
}

my @pairs = pair_map {\@_} 1 .. 10;

pair_map {print "$_[0]: $_[1]\n"} %hash;
```

But since Perl has been around a while, most utility functions have probably been written already.  A search of CPAN will turn up many `map`-like functions that do various things.

I found that I frequently need to map over lists with various step sizes, so I wrote the `mapn` function in [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aGen).  This is a fully developed solution, so it includes an optimization when called in void context, and falls back to Perl's own `map` when `n == 1`:

```
sub mapn (&$@) {
    my ($sub, $n, @ret) = splice @_, 0, 2;
    croak '$_[1] must be >= 1' unless $n >= 1;

    return map $sub->($_) => @_ if $n == 1;

    my $want = defined wantarray;
    while (@_) {
        local *_ = \$_[0];
        if ($want) {push @ret =>
              $sub->(splice @_, 0, $n)}
        else {$sub->(splice @_, 0, $n)}
    }
    @ret
}
```

Both `pair_map` and `mapn` utilize an advanced feature of Perl subroutines called prototypes.  These prototypes are not argument validation tools (like in many other languages).  Rather, they tell perl to interpret calls to the functions in a special way (similar to the way some other builtin functions are used).  In this case, the `&` portion of the prototype tells perl that the first argument to these functions can be written as a bare block, just like a normal `map` call.

Comment: I never said it did not have one. I wanted to write my own, just as I did in about any other language. As a learning helper. But your other answer helped me a bit with understanding perl subs, thanks.